# Azure Notification Hub, what is 'top' when retrieving Registrations

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub, notificationhubclient

The Azure `NotificationHubClient` has a function called GetRegistrationsByChannelAsync, and one of the parameters is an int called `top`, as shown below.

I assumed top is referring to the max number of retrieve, e.g top 100 items. But at the same time it could be referring to the location to start the retrieval, for example top = 100 would start the retrieval at position 100 onwards.

However, the documentation says top refers to "the location of the registration".

I am certainly missing something obvious, but what does `top` really refer to here?

[image]